# Is it possible to turn off all messages for a specific mathematica file?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding, usage-messages

I have a general question.
I have a big Mathematica file, which sometimes comes with some messages.

Is it possible to turn off all messages forever in this notebook/file?

BR
Mads

Comment: Assuming we are talking about a notebook run with Shift+Enter then you can Off/On in CellProlog/Epilog.

Comment: Hi Kina, its a dynamic notebook which has to be converted to af CDF enterprise file. So the shift Enter is not an option.

Comment: Hi Bill, Quiet doesnt work.

Comment: @MadsM it depends how your app works, if all 'actions' are run 'within Manipulate body', then just wrap the body with Quiet. If you have a more modular setup with buttons etc then you need to decorate all your actions with Quiet.

Comment: Hi @kuba - I figured out a solution wit "Off"